# I need help finding the arithmetic mean in my Python program

Tags: python-3.x

I have written almost all of my program, except I am stuck on this certain part. I need to write an average out to figure all students final grades out as a statistic of the course. Students name and final grade have been appended to an external file (keep in mind more students and grades can be appended).

Here is what I have so far, any input is highly appreciated.

```
fname = input("What is the file name?")
file1 = open(fname,'r')
sum = 0.0
count = 0
for line in file1:
    sum = sum + eval(line)                                     
    count = count + 1

print("\nThe average of the numbers is", sum/count)
```

in line 6 (`sum = sum + eval(line)`) I keep getting

```
syntax error:  unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)
```

I don't know enough about Python to know what this means. Can someone show me in code? And for reference external file is formatted like this for example:

```
tom jones,100,
bill smith,89,
```

And so on.

Comment: evaling the line makes no sense.  Parse the integers out of the lines.  (Or, if they're actually split by commas and not integers, then split on comma and iterate over that and parse the ints out.)

Comment: `eval`? ARGH! (I quote an expression used widely in the JavaScript community: "eval is evil".)

Comment: You may want to use the `csv` module.

Comment: Seeing now that the format is what it is, what you should do, Emily Ball, is loop over each line (exactly how you're doing) and then split on the commas.  The 1st element (0 indexed) will be your number, and you can add it to sum.  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split  Edit:  Chris is right.  Would be easier to use the csv module since it will parse quotes that internally have a comma and so on correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stud.py", line 6, in <module>
    sum = sum + eval(line)
  File "<string>", line 1
    tom jones,100,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because you are trying to evaluate "`tom jones,100,`" as a Python expression. This is not a valid Python expression. Not to mention that calling [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) on an arbitrary string is a very bad idea.

You need to [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the line, using `','` as a delimiter. Then you need to take the second field (100), and convert that to an [`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int). You can add this `int` to your `sum` (or `total`) and continue.

N.B: [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in function in Python and you are hiding it with your variable of the same name. I recommend using another work, such as `total`.

Good luck!

Comment: I just do not understand without seeing code...sorry I am very new to this

Comment: I cannot do your homework for you. I can only explain why it your code is behaving in the way it is and point you in the right direction. If you follow the links in my answer, you should have enough information to complete your task.

Comment: `int(line.split(',')[1])` should suffice. If you see `list index out of range`, then your input doesn't match the sample you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should try to get into [Python interactive mode](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode). It makes it easier to play with small bits of code, because you can immediately see what happens.

Instead of using eval, you can use [str.split](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to split your string into values. Start up the interactive interpreter, and run the following code line by line:

```
a = '1,2,3'
b = a.split(',')
print b
print b[0]
print b[0] + b[1]
print float(b[0]) + float(b[1])
```

The reason `b[0] + b[1]` print as '12' is because they are still strings. You need to tell python to handle them as numbers (using float()) before they work like you expect.

---

For extra credit, you can try to use the [Python csv library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html) to read and parse your file:

```
# Tell Python that you are going to use the csv (comma separated value) library
import csv

# Open the file
file = open('marks.csv')

# Use the csv library to read the file, instead of using "for line in file1"
markReader = csv.reader(file)

# Using this for means that each line is read as a list of strings. 
for row in markReader:

    # Now we get the string we want from the list. 0 would get the name, 1 gets the mark
    number_as_string = row[1]

    # We now make the string an actual number, because if we add '10' + '20', we get '1020' instead of 30.        
    number = float(number_as_string)
```

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I adapted the code from the library reference example. As for the question being homework, teach a man to fish.

Comment: I am not trying to get anyone to do my homework I said I have most of my program written I need help and I don't understand this it is an 11 week course and that is not enough time to learn everyhting I need to learn I am by far a cheater..thanks

Comment: I can send you the whole sh*t and caboodle of the program to show you

Comment: But the language you speak is like chinese to me

Comment: I've added some simpler example code that you should use the interactive interpreter for. It will help you understand your code, and how to fix it.